# A question regarding the probability density function of a uniformly distributed random variable.

Tags: probability-theory

In lecture, my teacher stated that the probability density function of a uniformly density random variable is not continuous. I can't seem to figure out why that is. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: In your course, a density function is probably defined for all real $x$. It is $\frac{1}{b-a}$ on $(a,b)$, but then crashes to $0$ for $x\lt a$ and $x\gt b$.